# You are not allowed to call openByUrl. OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, google-docs

You are not allowed to call openByUrl. OAuth 2.0

You are not allowed to call openByUrl. OAuth 2.0

I executes a script "A" in google text document "document" to retrieve the text of the document "Name Surname" I sent in a paper google spreadsheet "Spreadsheet"
with: SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ("")

The Script "A" is in a Library

This works well with documents whose script A "board" is OAuth 1.0, for against it does not work with the script A "board" is OAuth 2.0.

Error message referring me: You are not allowed to call openByUrl.

What should I do to run my new script OAuth 2.0
What should replace it by calling the SpreadsheetApp SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ("")?

var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gJHFDBHJj6peX1kjfdhlkskjFt2gFkU/edit#gid=3950BSV3");

here is the complete script up in the Library that runs perfectly if the document was created with  OAuth 1.0 but do not work if the document was created with  OAuth 2.0 .

```
/////    Facturer  Acte      ////

 function FacturerActe() {

  var regexp = /[^0-9]*/g ;// extrait la chaine de caractère avant la chaine numérique
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
  var result = regexp.exec(doc);
  var PrenomNom = new RegExp(result,"gm"); 
 Logger.log(PrenomNom.getText);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gj6peXR3hjvj51FxDFt2gFkU/edit#gid=395019283");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"y");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A40");
  cell.setNote("Aujourd'hui est un nouveau jour ! Nous sommes le :"+date);

  selectFirstEmptyRow (); // Place le curseur sur la premiere ligne Vide de la Colonne "B"
}

 //* Placez le curseur de l'utilisateur actuel dans la première cellule de la première ligne vide.
 //*
function selectFirstEmptyRow ()  { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gj6peXR3hjvj51FxDFt2gFkU/edit#gid=395019283");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"y");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
  var regexp = /[^0-9]*/g ;// extrait la chaine de caractère avant la chaine numérique

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
  var result = regexp.exec(doc);
  var regexp = /\s[A-Z a-z]+/g ;// extrait les espaces devant et derriere Nom Prenom
//* Extrait les blancs

  var result = regexp.exec(result);

///  var result = result.replace(/^[\r\n]+|\.|[\r\n]+$/g, "");// extrait les espaces devant et derriere Nom Prenom  GAS D'ONT WORK

  sheet . setActiveSelection ( sheet . getRange ( "B" + getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow ())).setValue(result) ;
   Logger.log(result.getText);
}

/**
 * " Trouve la première ligne vide la Colonne "B" " de checker de Mogsdad.
 */ 
function getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow ()  { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rWt8JEGbYM29-W4tI2gj6peXR3hjvj51FxDFt2gFkU/edit#gid=395019283");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-"+"mm"+"-"+"y");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);
  var range = sheet . getDataRange (); 
  var values = range . getValues (); 
  var row =  1 ; 
  for  ( var row = 1 ; row < values . length ; row ++)  { 
    if  (! values [ row ]. join ( "" ))  break ; 
  } 

  return  ( row + 1 ); 

}

 /////   Fin   Facturer  Acte      ////
```

Comment: do you also get an error when using openById() ?https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)

Comment: yes i obtain an error with Document created with OAuth 2.0 but work perfectly with Document with OAuth 1.0  onboard .

Comment: Sorry i'm still not able to understand the scenario, could you explain a little bit more? what do you mean with "Oauth 1.0 onboard"?

Comment: Still not clear. What does oauth have to do here? Wxplain in detail how you created the document "using oauth 1.0"